# Is there any WSO2I.S REST API to pass an old and new password in case user forgot?

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I'm using WSO2 I.S REST API to create users using SCIM 2.0 but I didn't find any method to use in case the user forgot his password. Is there any method? Have any example using a Java application calling this methods?

wso2-is-5.11.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please have a look on this document[1] for information on the REST APIs related to the password and username recovery, available in WSO2 Identity Server 5.11.0.
Refer to this WSO2 Identity Server documentation[2] to get to know more about the password recovery feature.

Also you can use SCIM2 APIs patch requests[3] to update the password of a user without using recovery APIs.

Following is an example curl command to update the password of a user by the admin using SCIM2 Users Endpoint.

```
curl -X PATCH 'https://localhost:9443/scim2/Users/<user-id>' \
-H 'accept: application/scim+json' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/scim+json' \
-H 'Authorization: Basic <base64 encoded(admin username:admin password)>' \
-d '{ "schemas": [ "urn:ietf:params:scim:api:messages:2.0:PatchOp" ], "Operations": [ { "op": "replace", "value": { "password": "newPassword" } } ]}'
```

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS511/apidocs/account-recovery/

[2] https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/learn/password-recovery/#password-recovery

[3] https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/develop/scim2-rest-apis/#/Users%20Endpoint/patchUser